# GnuTLS Libnettle 3.4 was not found

Tags: configure, gnutls, nettle

When I try to configure GnuTLS I'm getting the error that Libnettle 3.4 was not found. I've nettle 3.4.1-1 installed and the library files are present in /usr/lib. Even when I specify the environment variable `NETTLE_LIBS` directly (`export NETTLE_LIBS="-L/usr/lib -R/usr/lib -lnettle"`) it always throws out that message.

In the config.log is following more concrete message:

```
Package dependency requirement 'nettle >= 3.4.1' could not be satisfied.
Package 'nettle' has version '3.4', required version is '>= 3.4.1'
```

What I'am missing here?

Comment: What architecture do you have? Are you trying to cross-compile GnuTLS?

Comment: It is almost two months ago, but I think I have solved it by following the install instructions in the source code and building a new version of nettle (see: https://gitlab.com/gnutls/gnutls/blob/master/INSTALL.md#compilation).

Comment: Same issue for macOS 10.14.6: Libnettle 3.4.1 was not found. http://pkgconfig.freedesktop.org/releases/ can help.

Comment: In the config.log it is mentioned that we should `Package nettle was not found in the pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the directory containing 'nettle.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable. No package 'nettle' found`. I found nettle.pc inside <libfolder>/pkgconfig/.

Answer (score 7):

`gnutls` requires `PKG_CONFIG` to include `nettle.pc` and `hogweed.pc`, which were not copied to `/usr/lib/pkgconfig/` in my build of `nettle3` on Linux Ubuntu 20.04 x64, so I had to configure `gnutls3` as follows:

```sh
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$NETTLE3_ROOT:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH" ./configure --with-included-libtasn1 --with-included-unistring
```

where `NETTLE3_ROOT` is the path of `nettle3` sources.

Comment: Thanks for this solution! It is exactly what I have been looking for.

Comment: By the way, for my PKG_CONFIG_PATH to work I needed to use `"/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"` in my case

Answer (score 2):

when you install `nettle`, try to specify the install path to `/usr/`, otherwise it will use the default `/usr/local/`.

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/ && make && make install
```

`gnutls` will search dependent in `/usr/`.

Comment: I tried this but for some reason it didn't work for my setup.

Comment: it didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

This package worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install nettle-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

On my system I had to do the following:

- Install the `pkg-config` utility, which was missing on my system
- Configure the environment variable `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to include the pkgconfig directory under the prefix where libnettle was installed
- Configure the libnettle installation using the following configure flags: `./configure --disable-openssl --enable-shared --enable-mini-gmp` (the `--enable-mini-gmp` flag causes libhogweed to be built)

Answer (score 0):

For ARM64 architecture:

Download nettle 3.6 source package.

```
cd nettle-3.6
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/
sudo make
sudo make install
cd gnutls-3.7.9
./configure --with--included-libtasn1 --with-included-unistring -without-p11-kit
make
sudo make install
```