# configure GnuTLS - libnettle 3.4.1 was not found - OS X Lion

Tags: configure, pkg-config, gnutls, nettle

I'm trying to build `GnuTLS-3.x` on my **OS X Lion** and here is my configure command:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/gnutls-3.4.9 --with-included-libtasn1 --without-p11-kit
```

It ends up

```
checking for NETTLE... no
configure: error:
  ***
  *** Libnettle 3.4.1 was not found.
```

though libnettle-3.4.1 is installed under `/usr/local/libnettle-3.4.1` and its `pkg-config` file `libnettle.pc` is defined under `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig` (I've built `nettle-4.3.1` from source successfully)

I've read the stackoverflow post [GnuTLS Libnettle 3.4 was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53790710/gnutls-libnettle-3-4-was-not-found) but it didn't help a bit. All other posts on the Internet didn't help either.

I'm stuck on this error. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: same issue for macOS 10.14.6: Libnettle 3.4.1 was not found. http://pkgconfig.freedesktop.org/releases/ can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the cause of the problem. It was the incorrectly defined environment variable `PKG_CONFIG`. It was set just to the installation directory of the `pkg-config` i.e. `/usr/local/pkg-config-0.28`

However it looks like that it must have been set to the full path plus the `pkg-config` command itself, like: `/usr/local/pkg-config-0.28/bin/pkg-config`

Answer (score 1):

`PKG_CONFIG` should include `nettle.pc` and `hogweed.pc`, which were not copied to `/usr/lib/pkgconfig/` in my build of `nettle3` on Linux Ubuntu 20.04 x64, so I had to configure `gnutls3` as follows:

```sh
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$NETTLE3_ROOT:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH" ./configure --with-included-libtasn1 --with-included-unistring
```

where `NETTLE3_ROOT` is the path of `nettle3` sources.

Comment: Just seen the answer. Good to see further information on the usage of `Nettle` and anything related to `GNUTLS` as they are very inclined to cause dirty problems on `macOS`